# Select with NavLink doesn't work with useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, react-hooks

I have created a Select which is used to navigate through page. Select options are NavLinks. It looks like that:

```
<Select
   placeholder={PLACEHOLDER}
   items={ITEMS} // array of NavLinks
   {...selectState} // State of select option change
   className={style.select}
/>
```

After Option change I call function:

```
function useSelectState(initValue) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initValue);
    return { value, onChange: setValue }  
}
```

So I get correct initValue, but value never changes and I am not able to setValue. Maybe anyone had same problem?

UseSelectState:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: ƒ, key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {label: "Home", path: "/"}
```

Comment: Can you show how select state looks like and what are you using for Select

Comment: You mean how the object looks like?

Comment: I meant is the object returned by `useSelectState`

Comment: Added useSelectState object

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be, that with the onChange method you got an event as a parameter not the value itself.

Maybe you can try this:

```
function useSelectState(initValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initValue);
  return { value, onChange: (event) => setValue(event.target.value) }  
}
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Mantas try logging out the onChange parameter to see where the value is. For example add the following property to select onChange={event => console.log('event',event)}

Answer (score 1):

`useState` should be called inside your render. You should not call it yourself after any updates.

For a simple select:

```
function useSelectState(initValue) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initValue);
    return { value, onChange: e => setValue(e.target.value) }  
}

function MyComponent(props) {
    const params = useSelectState(props.initValue);

    return (
        <select {...params}>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    );
}
```

For a list of `NavLink` you probably don't need anything of the above. react-router will update the `location` and you can use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to access it and update your `Select` accordingly. Alternatively you can just rely on [activeClassName](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) and use only css to show the current value.